# Strange CLassNotFoundException when using SimpleXML 2.7.1 on Mac

Tags: java, xml-parsing, simple-framework

When parsing XML using SimpleXML on Mac OSX I get the following strange ClassNotFoundException.

I really don't understand why SimpleXML is even trying to use this class?

Any ideas? How can I stop this?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: media-desktop
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.Loader.load(Loader.java:50)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.readValue(TreeStrategy.java:163)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.read(TreeStrategy.java:102)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getOverride(Source.java:360)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getConversion(Factory.java:207)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getOverride(Factory.java:139)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ObjectFactory.getInstance(ObjectFactory.java:63)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:139)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:543)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:521)
```

Comment: For more information.. It turns out that the XML was badly formatted but the exception seems irrelevant to the situation of badly formatted XML..

Comment: Will you please provide snippet??

Comment: I don't think you need one. A web page with a link to the XML had been downloaded by accident instead of the XML file itself. It was trying to parse the wrong document. My guess is that media-desktop was the first thing that SimpleXML thought was a tag and trying to map it to a class.